# Отображение дочерних элементов данного элемента, а не всех

Tags: vue.js

При нажатии на "Переключить" все списки появляются, а мне нужно только тот список дочерних элементов, на родителя которого я нажал.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active до версии 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu" @click="show = !show">Переключить

  <transition name="fade">
    <ol v-if="show">
      <li>Первый</li>
      <li>Второй</li>
      <li>Третий</li>
    </ol>
  </transition>
  </li>
    <li class="menu" @click="show = !show">Переключить

  <transition name="fade">
    <ol v-if="show">
      <li>Четвёртый</li>
      <li>Пятый</li>
      <li>Шестой</li>
    </ol>
  </transition>
  </li>
    <li class="menu" @click="show = !show">Переключить

  <transition name="fade">
    <ol v-if="show">
      <li>Седьмой</li>
      <li>Восьмой</li>
      <li>Девятый</li>
    </ol>
  </transition>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто каждомю родителю присваиваю разные значения show в data: show1, show2, show3.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.demo',
  data: {
    show1: true,
    show2: true,
    show3: true
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active до версии 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu" @click="show1 = !show1">Переключить

  <transition name="fade">
    <ol v-if="show1">
      <li>Первый</li>
      <li>Второй</li>
      <li>Третий</li>
    </ol>
  </transition>
  </li>
    <li class="menu" @click="show2 = !show2">Переключить

  <transition name="fade">
    <ol v-if="show2">
      <li>Четвёртый</li>
      <li>Пятый</li>
      <li>Шестой</li>
    </ol>
  </transition>
  </li>
    <li class="menu" @click="show3 = !show3">Переключить

  <transition name="fade">
    <ol v-if="show3">
      <li>Седьмой</li>
      <li>Восьмой</li>
      <li>Девятый</li>
    </ol>
  </transition>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, но если только эти списки не генерируются и их количество заранее известно.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, ссори) Удалил претензию)